# Is there a windows 7 utility that can verify that an ssl certificate matches a key file?

Tags: windows-7, ssl-certificate

The title says it all.  When I google for this, it mentions openssl, but I think that must be a unix utility because I can't find it on windows 7.

Comment: Not specific to Windows 7, but you can use this if you trust them: https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [The Win32 OpenSSL Installation Project](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html).